# Flexslider views messing up my other images styles

Tags: javascript

Installed flexslider and the flexslider views module.
But when in enable them my other image styles don't work no more.
In my view everything (image style) is ok.
But on my page it doesn't work.
www.thewizard.eu
Someone advise?

Thanks,
Tom

Comment: I don't see where the images don't work. Only your volume controls are not working (wrong path). Nice job on Suske en Wiske btw. :)

Comment: In brands we work with, the images has to be smaller. If I remove the flexslider it works.

Answer (score 0):

You need to remove a flexslider css style:

```
.flexslider .slides img {
display: block;
width: 100%; }
```

The **width** setting is messing your brands up.

Comment: Nope that didn't do the trick.

Comment: What exactly did you do? How does your css look? If you use firebug and disable the width setting, your brand logos look as they probably should.

Comment: Removed what you told me too. In the css of the theme. strange did it with firebug and that worked.

Comment: Remove means creating a css style that takes in consideration what else is affected by this style. Actually you would write just an exception like: 
.field-name-field-clients-logo img {
    width: auto !important;
}